# Lambda function is outputting memory address instead of actual values

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

when i run the code i get a memory location as an output

<function  at 0x00000200FF8A5E50>

```
val = (lambda colmns:(colmns.max + colmns.min)/2
print(val)
```

Comment: You need to actually use the `lambda`. If you try to print it directly, you will get the address of where the lambda code lives in memory.

Comment: Right.  Assuming you have an array, do `print(val(array))`.

Comment: `val` is a function object, it isn't a "memory address", when you print a function object, that is how it is represented, just like any function, try `def foo(): return 42` then `print(foo)`

Comment: Why did you *expect* a different output?

Answer (score 0):

A lambda is just an anonymous function object and that's why it prints that way. In fact, as soon as you assign it to a variable... then why have a lambda in the first place? Might as well do

```
def foo(colmns): 
    return (colmns.max + colmns.min)/2
```

And then it wouldn't be too surprising that `print(foo)` is `<function 0x...>`.

Comment: @hghebrem - what are you talking about? The thing you seemed to have missed is that lambda creates a function object, and that's what I illustrated with the `def`. But I still needed to wrap that back specifically to the question about where "<function at 0x00000200FF8A5E50>" comes from. When you see it as a `def` I didn't think there would be any question about why is printed as a "function".